# Show/hide all figures drawing in drawingManager

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

My project is related with gps and tracking system. I draw geofences on google maps api v3 with drawingManager. And i need a button, clicking on which it will be show/hide all drawingManager figures. In my project i also use angularJS. I have 2 different directives. In 1-st i declare drawingManager

```
var polyOption = {
    fillColor: '#ffff00',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    clickable: true,
    editable: true,
    zIndex: 1
};
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
            ]
     },
     circleOptions: polyOption,
     rectangleOptions: polyOption,
     polygonOptions: polyOption,
     polylineOptions: polyOption,
});
scope.geozonesConfig.tempDrawManagerVar = true;
scope.geozonesConfig.tempDrawManagerHide = false;
drawingManager.setMap(map);


google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.      
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        // To hide:              
        // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
        // mouses down on it.
        var newShape = e.overlay;                      
        newShape.type = e.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
          scope.$apply (function () {
            scope.geozonesConfig.showGeozoneConfig = true;
          });
        });
    setSelection(newShape);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
buildColorPalette();
```

there is my button. i used ng-click:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="{{ 'Add geozone' | translate }}" ng-click="onGeozoneClick()"><i class="icon-globe"></i></a>
```

`and my function is located into another directive:

```
 scope.onGeozoneClick = function () {
            alert('Show/Hide all figures');
 };
```

How can i show/hide these drawingManager figures? Thanks.

**EDIT:** Update from OP's reply as an Answer

How can i do it in js? I dont know how to refer to my figures. And there is no any method in google maps api for these figures, as i know. Now i tried to do it using visible property of figuresOptions:
`var anchorShowHideFigure = true; var polyOption = {visible = anchorShowHideFigure };`
 and then i want change flag to false after click on button. If i will write in my 1-st directive: 
`function showHideDrawingFigures () { anchorShowHideFigure = false; };`
 in console i get: "showHideDrawingFigures is not definied". if i will write it into 2-nd directive i get: "anchorShowHideFigure is not definied" i get this, because my html file use 2-nd directive. sorry if i explained intricately –

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ng-show](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ng-show&oq=ng-show&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1128j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) & [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directives for this.

Create one flag say showFigures, in $scope. For toggling the fla

```
$scope.onGeozoneClick = function () {
        $scope.showFigures = false;
 };
```

In HTML,

```
<div ng-show="showFigures"></div>
```

Comment: There is one problem. I dont have any div or something. I have only figures on google maps api drawing by drawingManager. I can not refer to them in any way. They simply are on the map and how to apply them, I do not know.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to do it out-of-angular(normal JS way). [Angular google maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) may be worth looking at and may solve your problem.

Comment: How can i do it in js? I dont know how to refer to my figures. And there is no any method in google maps api for these figures, as i know.

Comment: Now i tried to do it using visible property of figuresOptions:
var polyOption = {
                      fillColor: '#ffff00',
                      fillOpacity: 0.4,
                      strokeWeight: 1,
                      clickable: true,
                      editable: true,
                      zIndex: 1
            };

Comment: Now i tried to do it using visible property of figuresOptions:
var anchorShowHideFigure = true;
var polyOption = {visible = anchorShowHideFigure };

and then i want change flag to false after click on button. If i will write in my 1-st directive:
function showHideDrawingFigures () {
      anchorShowHideFigure = false;
};

in console i get: "showHideDrawingFigures  is not definied".

if i will write it into 2-nd directive i get:
"anchorShowHideFigure is not definied"

i get this, because my html file use 2-nd directive. sorry if i explained intricately

Comment: I am not aware of much internals of maps api, however, I can say that just changing non-angular javascript variable(visible in your case) will not have any effect on visibility of the drawing. If you can get hold of DOM object of the drawing somehow, it can be done. e.g.          document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility="hidden";